# How to make Zabbix agent use multi threading to execute Userparameter?

Tags: zabbix

I'm using Userparameter type with a `curl` shell command to check if a website live,if the site domain number is more than 1000 then, I set the check time as 5 minutes (in zabbix-agent active mode), but I found that many check items are in the queue waiting for a long time more than 10 minutes. So how can I improve the check speed

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, Zabbix agent processes active items in a serial fashion [per server].

Possible solution - have an item that [schedules an `atd` job](https://zabbix.org/wiki/Escaping_timeouts_with_atd), then sends data to trapper item[s].

In the future, the [agent rewrite in Go](https://blog.zabbix.com/magic-of-new-zabbix-agent/8460/) will have parallel active check processing.

Comment: thanks, solved my problem. I changed to trapper item[s].

Comment: trapper is very useful for me :)!